# GPG error when trying to sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates, wine

When I try doing `sudo apt update` this happens:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? It appears to be looking for ubuntu jammy InRelease

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt update
```

as the wiki says https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: it works, thanks. It should be better if that trick wasn't needed